# Javascript function does not work on onclick of checkbox

Tags: javascript, function, checkbox, onclick

I try to call a Javascript function through an onclick attribute of a checkbox.

The js should show another checkbox if the first one is checked etc.

Now the function isnt working. I tried to use just an alert() for testing without any result...

```
  Fitness:<input type="checkbox" id="fitnessCheck" onclick="checkFunction()">
    Beauty:<input type="checkbox" id="beautyCheck">
    Streetwear:<input type="checkbox" id="streetwearCheck">
    Luxus:<input type="checkbox" id="luxusCheck" onClick="checkFunction()">

Datenschutz: <input style="display:none" type="checkbox"  id="datenschutzCheck">
<script>
checkFunction(){
//get Checkboxes
var fitnessCheckbox = document.getElementById("fitnessCheck");
var beautyCheckbox = document.getElementById("beautyCheck");
var streetwearCheckbox = document.getElementById("streetwearCheck");
var luxusCheckbox = document.getElementById("luxusCheck");
var datenschutzCheckbox = document.getElementById("datenschutzCheck");

if(fitnessCheckbox.checked == true || beautyCheckbox.checked == true || streetwearCheckbox.checked == true || luxusCheckbox.checked == true){
    datenschutzCheckbox.style.display ="block"; 
}
}</script>
```

Comment: It seems you are missing the `function` keyword if you are not using typescript or es6

Comment: Yes, the function keyword is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to define a function in JavaScript.
Correct your function as below;

```
function checkFunction(){
}
```

Alternatively, remove the onclick attribute from HTML and put it in the JavaScript as defined below

```
var fitnessCheckbox = document.getElementById("fitnessCheck");
fitnessCheckbox.onclick() = function() {
// access properties using this keyword
if ( this.checked ) {
    // if checked ...
    alert( this.value );
} else {
    // if not checked ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare the function checkFunction().
You can do it in many ways such as:

```
function checkFunction() {
// code here
}
```

or

```
var checkFunction = function() {
// code here
}
```

etc, depending on how you are going to use the function.